# Angular and HTML5 fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my main controller, I've got a function that toggles true/false for a fullscreen browser state like so:

```
// Full Screen toggle
$scope.fsState = false;
$scope.fullScreen = function fullScreen(){
  function launchFS(element) {
    if (element.requestFullScreen) element.requestFullScreen();
    else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
  function cancelFS() {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) document.cancelFullScreen();
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
  }
  if($scope.fsState == false) launchFS(document.documentElement);
  else cancelFS(); $scope.fsState = !$scope.fsState;
};
```

And in the view...

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="fullScreen()">Toggle Fullscreen</button>
```

This works fine, except for when i navigate to another page within the SPA. Every time i make a selection from the main navigation (which is also in the same controller), the page jumps out of fullscreen. Any idea why Angular.js is doing this or what can be done so it maintains the state between route changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably removing the fullscreen element and readding it. It should be on top of your ui-view, something like

```
<body>
  <div class="fullscreen-container">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can also use this project to avoid having to call vendor specific functions
https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull